# need pay TRX when enought bandwidth

Tags: tron, trx

I'm trying send usdt. Why i need pay extra TRX for fee ([0.349 for 349 bandwidth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bcpD.png)) when i have enought bandwidth ([598](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvxMt.png))? If you wait until the next day when the counter is full. Еhen the commission disappears. But I still don’t understand why having 598 is not enough when you need 349.

I expect that I won't burn trx since I have enough bandwidth